# JSON format error even though echo matches with DataTables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, datatables

I run a lengthy PHP script I was modifying to PDO formatting as opposed to crappy mysql Db calls. At the end of the script, the $output is json encoded with:

```
echo json_encode( $output );
```

When I run the two scripts, the output to screen is IDENTICAL but my jquery DataTables program returns an error on the PDO encoded results and not the mysql return.

I have run regex's on the two results and they are IDENTICAL so why this is happening is beyond me.

Anybody ever had the same issue?

## EDIT

DataTables error states:

> DataTables warning: JSON data from
>   server could not be parsed. This is
>   caused by a JSON formatting error.

Comment: This is when it's time to pull out the packet sniffer.

Comment: @Ignacio - ha, the script is from a "trusted" source but I am at a total loss as to what is going on

Comment: I assume regex would have probably taken care of this, but have you examined both strings in a hex editor?

Comment: @JM4 - "output to screen", can explain more? (a web page, or stdout in a cli)

Comment: @Andrew - I have not. I don't even know what that is.

Comment: @ajreal - output to a localhost webpage

Comment: @JM4 - What does the error on jquery DataTables said ? Or can you embed the error details into your question ?

Answer (score 1):

One method to use is to grab the JSON return from Firebug (or Webkit's inspector or whatever) and run it through http://jsonlint.com . If the JSON string is identical, then I would guess that there is something else being output (perhaps a PHP warning, or just an echo of a string somewhere) which is causing the parsing to fail. DataTables makes use of the JSON parser built into jQuery 1.4, and will give this error when the parser cannot decode the string.

If that doesn't help, are you able to give us a link to the page?

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem too. Just because I use jquery 1.5.1.
after I change to user 1.4.4, the problem disappear.

Answer (score 1):

For all those people that come here from google, try this:

```
echo '('.json_encode( $output ).')';
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issues, but only when using **PDO with prepared statements**. JSONLint validates the output, but DataTables just does not accept it.
I've created my own function using getJSON to fetch JSON data from my PHP datasource, and this actually works.
Additionally I've created a duplicate datasource in which I am using mysqli, and when viewing the output in my browser, and running a compare on the 2 outputs in notepad++, both are identical.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error and used a validator to make sure that my format was valid using this: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

It was valid and it just turns out that my PHP script was "echoing" other data due to a stupid mistake of mine.

**Try calling the script that generates the JSON in your browser directly** to see if other things are being displayed, messing up the JSON code that your dataTable receives.