# DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error. (ASP.NET)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, datatables

I am working in ASP.NET VS2010 and C#.NET as a backend language, I am not using MVC. 
I am getting a problem to load data from server side. Its showing correct number of rows but without data. My JSON response is valied Json string.

Anyone have the idea how to resolve this problem???????

Here is a the string that i am getting in response

```
{"sEcho": 1,"iTotalRecords": 2,"iTotalDisplayRecords": 2,"aaData": [{"Name":"IT","DescEn":"Information Technology","DescAr":"testing","CreatedOn":"18-03-2013","CreatedBy":"1"},{"Name":"HR","DescEn":"Human Resource","DescAr":"testing","CreatedOn":"18-03-2013","CreatedBy":"1"}]}
```

And here is the html

```
<table id='example' class="datatable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            DescEn
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            DescAr
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            CreatedOn
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            CreatedBy
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

And here is a JS script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "bDestroy": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "aaSorting": [[1, "desc"]],
                "sAjaxSource": '<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("Request/GroupPage.aspx") %>',
                "aoColumns": [
           { "aaData": "Name" },
            { "aaData": "DescEn" },
            { "aaData": "DescAr" },
            { "aaData": "CreatedOn" },
            { "aaData": "CreatedBy" }
        ]
            });
        });
```

any one have the idea how to resolve this problem???????

Comment: how do you serialize object on backend? You're getting escaped string wich isn't valid as json

Comment: i am reading data from database and then saving that data in a C# string for quot on both sides of a word i need to use escape sequence

Comment: so you store json string in database?

Comment: can you tell me that my js script is fine????? or is there anyother way to load this reponse????? i am getting response without any error.

Comment: my string is valid json string now tell me why its not showning records in grid???????????????

Comment: @Sergio i have resolved this issue by creating a class of JSON response and then serialize that object on the response stream and this issue has resolved.  btw thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please at least search for a solution on google. I think I don't have to repeat the same answer here.

http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/4133/datatables-warning-json-data-from-server-could-not-be-parsed./p1

[DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330746/datatables-warning-json-data-from-server-could-not-be-parsed-this-is-caused-by)

[JSON format error even though echo matches with DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221681/json-format-error-even-though-echo-matches-with-datatables)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1674808.aspx/1

http://forums.xereo.net/threads/datatables-warning-json-data-from-server-not-could-be-parsed-this-is-caused-by-a-json-formatting-e.601/

https://code.google.com/p/cpassman/issues/detail?id=211

Comment: i have resolved this issue by creating a class of JSON response and then serialize that object on the response stream and this issue has resolved.